# Android In App Billing - how to change a boolean value upon purchasing in app product

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want to implement In app billing to enable a particular feature with my app.  I've modified the Android sample code and it is working fine.  However, now I need to implement the change to my app once the user buys the in app product.  My plan is to have a boolean value set to false and once the users buys the in app product, the boolean value will be set to true and then a previously hidden button will be revealed.  My questions is where in the billing code can I place the code to change the boolean value of my app.  From all my searches I've only found 'references' to 'once the transaction is successful', etc, but that is not helpful.  Any specific references to code from the android sample billing application would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist that information, so just setting a boolean flag won't do it. The Dungeons app uses a database, so refer to that part of the code for a sample: the `PurchaseDatabase` class and its `insertOrder()`, `updatePurchasedItem()` methods. For you your case (single product/feature), setting a boolean preference will probably do.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I didn't mention it but I would persist the boolean flag using SharedPreferences.  My problem is where exactly do I set the flag and then save it to sharedpreferences.  I'd only want to do it when I know the user paid successfully for the specific in app purchase and the transaction went through successfully.  I really need some help with the specific code and where it would go.  For Example (if (productID.equals(111) && purchasedState.equals("PURCHASED")) {feature1==true;}

Comment: Follow the sample code, see where it calls `updatePurcahsedItem()`, replace with your own preferences based code. Generally, you'd want to do this when you get a purchase state change notification and the state is PURCHASED. You should really go over the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) a couple of times to get the whole picture.